# #ref:java.util.LinkedHashMap error in Karate tool

Tags: karate

```
* def template1 = {"name1":"value1", "name2":"value2"}
* def template2 = template1

* Def jsontemplate = ({json1: template1, json2:template2})


* Print jsontemplate
```

Result :

```
  "json1": {
"name1": "value1",
"name2": "value2"
},
  "json2": "#ref:java.util.LinkedHashMap"
}
```

I am confused on how to overcome this issue. Can you help?

Comment: For what it's worth, ` * match jsontemplate == {json1: '#(template1)', json2: '#(template1)'}` works. Why do you want to print it?

Comment: @AutomationTester Karate is being smart here when *printing* the tree because it detected an infinite recursion :) behind the scenes all your data is ok. kindly mark the answer from Alex J as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `* copy template2 = template1` instead of `* def template2 = template1`, then `print` will give you:

```
{  "json1": {
    "name1": "value1",
    "name2": "value2"
    },
  "json2": {
    "name1": "value1",
    "name2": "value2"
    }
}
```